# What are the theoretical maximum frenzy/endurance/power charges one character can use?

Tags: path-of-exile

The Path of Exile gamepedia has a page dedicated to the theoretical max Dodge Chance one can get using a variety of Unique items, skills, and ascendancies, but fails to list anything about the possible ways to obtain the max amount of frenzy charges, endurance charges, and power charges.

The only reason I ask is because I can think of 3 builds that could utilize the three, but it's hard for me to figure out how I can max out charges.  Essentially:

- Scaling Raider (with any skill really) with Frenzy Charges
- Scaling Discharge using either Frenzy/Power/Endurance Charges
- Scaling Spell Damage via 2x Void Batteries using as many power charges possible.

What are the theoretically maximum amounts of charges I can equip for all 3 charge types?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## TL;DR

- Endurance  - 15
- Power - 18
- Frenzy - 17

## Sources

A quick note: To reach the maximum of a specific charge type, I'm assuming you're using two [Precursor's emblem](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Precursor%27s_Emblem) with +3 to the charge type you're trying to maximize.

Getting all required items to maximize the charges is extremely unlikely but it is possible in theory.

**All charges** (**12 charges**)

Per default you can have **3 charges** of any type.

Every class can get **+3** to maximum for each of the charge types from the skill tree.

[Getting the required nodes isn't a problem in terms of skill-points](https://poeplanner.com/ABIAAIkAEiYAAEGw2CHAsw4Pq21s53To1gW1jb9RRzB8fytW-nfXFHUY23TxIWBAoF4TktAS4e9OYVKGYDpSDjwUcfjru-2RzuoY9zJyqayqWfOfPi3SPs-95jY9VYWlyyyFWhobyOOEDdFjQw5IEZZ_xqKjwfOVIC0fTLMgblAwcg9mnhZAhX2RR4CzAAAAAAA=) but the viability of it is another topic (although that's part of not the question).

With two extremely well rolled [Precursor's Emblem](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Precursor%27s_Emblem) you'll get an additional maximum **+ 6** to each charge aswell.

**Endurance** (**3 additional charges**):

For classes you'll need to be either a [Juggernaut or a Chieftain](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Endurance_charge#Ascendancy_passive_skills) to get **+1**.

[Deaths door](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Death%27s_Door) is the only specific slot item that will give you **+1** to endurance charges.

Apart from that you'll need a [lucky Shaper roll on a 2 handed weapon](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Endurance_charge#Shaper) to increase it by **+1**.

**Power** (**6 additional charges**):

To get an additional **+1** you'll have to ascend as either an [Assassin, Trickster or Occultist](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Power_charge#Ascendancy_passive_skills).

You will be able to get a whopping **+4** power charges from uniques with the following items:

- [The Aylardex](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/The_Aylardex) **+1**
- [Storm Prison](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Storm_Prison) **+1** (although there are multiple wands with +1)
- [Malachai's Loop](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Malachai%27s_Loop) **+2**

Additionally if you're lucky with a [Vaal Orb or corrupted drop](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Power_charge#Corrupted) you may find a **+1** on a helmet slot.

**Frenzy** (**4 additional charges**):

As [@A_S00](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/357452/what-are-the-theoretical-maximum-frenzy-endurance-power-charges-one-character-ca/357461#comment505122_357461) pointed out in his comment you can achieve a total of 17 charges if you're using the [Badge of the Brotherhood](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Badge_of_the_Brotherhood).

Otherwise the following options are available.

In terms of ascendencies, here you'll have to be either a [Trickster or Raider](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Frenzy_charge#Ascendancy_passive_skills) for a **+1**.

The only unique item that will give you additional charges are the [Darkray Vectors](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Darkray_Vectors) (**+1**).

For modifiers on yellow items you can either get lucky with a [corrupted roll on gloves](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Frenzy_charge#Corrupted) or with a [shaper roll on a two-handed weapon](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Frenzy_charge#Shaper) (**+1 each**)

Comment: Vaal Orbs can also offer +1 to maximum Endurance Charges, on boots.

Comment: You can get 17 Frenzy charges by using the method described here for Power Charges (minus The Aylardex), and then wearing [Badge of the Brotherhood](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Badge_of_the_Brotherhood).

Comment: @KRyan yes. I've deliberatiely excluded it from my answer since the unique item is in the boots slot.

Comment: You can corrupt unique items. In fact, since they are more fixed and you can get multiple copies of them, it’s often much less painful to try with uniques than with non-unique items.